# Converting a Bluetooth keyboard to a USB wireless receiver keyboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, keyboard, bluetooth

I had a tricky situation recently:

I had my Bluetooth adapter turned off by an accident from my mini PC (Skull Canyon) and I only have a Bluetooth keyboard, no wired keyboard, nor a wireless USB receiver keyboard. I have a USB wireless mouse, fortunately.

So I could NOT type anything on my terminal (I am using Ubuntu) to enable the Bluetooth adapter back on with the command below:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now bluetooth
```

So, I had to type the command above in my email account and sent it to myself from my Surface Go so I could open it from my mini PC, copied it with USB wireless mouse and pasted in the terminal.

But what if you don't have a second machine to back you up if this situation happens to you. What can it be done? The Bluetooth keyboard just becomes completely useless in a crisis like this. So what is the point of having it in the end?

Another situation that the Bluetooth keyboard becomes completely useless is when the time you need to install a fresh OS system, Ubuntu for instance. You will need to type to install at certain stages but the Bluetooth adapter and driver are not ready until you have installed the OS. You would need an old fashion wired keyboard or USB receiver keyboard to do that.

The only solution I can think off is to have a USB receiver wireless keyboard ready all the time for cases like this. But this is not ideal because you end up owning duplicates of things.

So, can we **convert** the Bluetooth keyboard to any Bluetooth devices to a **wireless USB receiver device** with some kind of converter or adapter?

I have been reading about Bluetooth adapters, Bluetooth receivers, Bluetooth transmitters but I don't think they are the answer (maybe I am wrong).

Any thoughts or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a USB to Bluetooth adapter. The Bluetooth adapter would be different to your built-in Bluetooth so would do the trick. There are lots of these so use Google to pick out what you need

Comment: what is a USB to Bluetooth adapter, can you give us an example? some links maybe?

Comment: Here is one:  https://www.primecables.ca/en/p-361060-cab-csrv40-usb-bluetooth-v40-wireless-mini-adapter-dongle-primecables?from_pla=google&sku=371026&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuZDtBRDvARIsAPXFx3BAPapZUgO5Rx1wMxVMSCcjpp4z1KOWUIGH4_dgT4frO_Ah7wIkShkaAk-BEALw_wcB#sku371026

Comment: Thanks. It is just a Bluetooth adapter, isn't it? Most modern computers have a built-in Bluetooth adapter already. Why can we make use of having a USB one?

Comment: True, but if you turn the built-in one off (as per above) then the adapter will serve as a backup for it

Comment: aw got ya. probably this is best the solution instead of buying duplicates of things! thanks!